# How does one define a generic wrapper interface type and use it as method return type in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the following: defining a wrapper interface type and have a calculate method that returns that wrapper, but it doesn't work:

```
public interface Wrapper<T> {
}

public interface Calculator<WrapperType extends Wrapper<?> {
   <T> WrapperType<T> calculate(Supplier<T> calculator);
}
```

The error is something like "Type Wrapper does not have type parameter". Is this something possible in Java?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Something like `public interface Calculator<T> {
       Wrapper<T> calculate(Supplier<T> calculator);
    }` would seem more intuitive to me.

Comment: I want the calculator to be able to compute generic output. The wrapper is kind of an object that contains the output and additional information (error code, error messages, exception during calculation, etc.)

Comment: You said the error is "something like" "Type Wrapper does not have type parameter". Could you post the actual error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't compile like this. You can't have this many levels of genericity in java, you're going to have to decide between

```
public interface Calculator<T> {
   Wrapper<T> calculate(Supplier<T> calculator);
}
```

and

```
public interface Calculator<T, WrapperType extends Wrapper<T>> {
   WrapperType calculate(Supplier<T> calculator);
}
```

The latter gives more flexibility at the cost of an additional complexity.

Comment: can you explain a little bit about  "you can't have this many levels of genericity in java" this?

Comment: I meant that if `X` is a generic type, you can never write `X<Y>`